# DateTime parsing C#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I cant parse this date, whats wrong?

```
 "Jul 15 2015 16: +0"
```

+0 its UTC added time, I want get time full in seconds.

UTC

```
Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", 
    DateTime.ParseExact("Jul 15 2015 16: +0", 
    "MMM dd yyyy HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"));
```

Error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"success\":true,\"price_prefix\":\"\",\"price_suffix\":\" pСѓР±.\",\"prices\":[[\"Jul 15 2015 16: +0\",1.745,\"6\"],[\"Jul 15 2015 17: +0\",1.78,\"5\"],[\"Jul 15 2015 18: +0\",1.65,\"7\"]]}";
            var prices = JObject.Parse(json)["prices"].Children()
                            .Select(j => new PriceItem
                            {
                                Date = (string)j[0],
                                Price = (float)j[1],
                                Count = (int)j[2]
                            });
            foreach (PriceItem priceItem in prices)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", DateTime.ParseExact(priceItem.Date, "MMM dd yyyy HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"));
                Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", priceItem.Price);
                Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", priceItem.Count);
                Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 10));
            }   
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    class PriceItem
    {
        public string Date { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: The date you are trying to parse also includes a colon and time zone, so `Jul 15 2015 16: +0` doesn't fit the format `MMM dd yyyy HH` try something like `MMM dd yyyy HH':' z`

Comment: String isn't distinguished as the valid DateTime value.

Comment: MMM dd yyyy HH':' z is work. Thank you!!!

Comment: I've updated post to match someones upvote... @deathnoob for future questions pleas provide error messages, small sample and avoid all sorts of "help me", "new here", "Thank you" text not directly related to the problem.

Comment: @Ron Beyer: Do you mind posting as an answer? It will avoid someone posting the exact same text as their own answer.

Comment: @sstan just did, with more explanation of what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.ParseExact` does just that, it *exactly* parses the input data. If the input data doesn't match, it will throw an exception (although there is a similar function called `DateTime.TryParseExact` that won't throw).

Your input data is `Jul 15 2015 16: +0` which includes the time zone and a separator character. You want to create a format string that exactly matches it, so you need to use `MMM dd yyyy HH':' z`. The colon is inside ' marks because it is interpreted as a time separator character by the parser, so you need to tell the formatter to "copy it as a literal" from the input string.

Your code then becomes:

```
Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}", 
    DateTime.ParseExact("Jul 15 2015 16: +0", 
    "MMM dd yyyy HH':' z", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("MMM dd, yyyy"));
```

And that should work.

See [Custom DateTime Format Strings (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.